# pmf of discrete distribution constructed from multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Given random vector $\vec{r}$ follows multivariate normal distribution $ \vec{r} \sim \mathcal{N}(\vec{0},\,\Sigma^{d \times d}) $. 
Construct a new boolean random vector $\vec{n} := \vec{r} > \vec{0}$.

Now what's the PMF for $\vec{n}$ ? and I'm most interested in the topmost likely samples from that distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Given a realization of objective random vector $\vec{n}= (0, 0, 1, 1, 0,..,)$:
We can group all the index of $0_s$ into a set $A$. and $1_s$ into a set $B$.

$P(\vec{N}) = P(\vec{R}_A <0, \vec{R}_B>0) = P(\vec{R}_A<0) - P(\vec{R}_A<0, \vec{R}_B<0) = P(\vec{R}_A<0) - P(\vec{R} <0)$

As $R \sim N(\vec{0}, \Sigma^{d \times d})$, and properties of normal distribution that any subset joint distribution is still normal. $P(\vec{R}<0) = F(\vec{0}), P(\vec{R}_A<0) = F_{R_A}(\vec{0})$.

Where $F$ is the cumulative density function of multivariate normal distribution.

The probability of a specific realization $\vec{n}$ using $A$ representation can be calculated:
Get the correlation matrix $R$ from $\Sigma$.

$$
P(A) = \frac{1}{det(R_A)} * e^{\frac{-\text{sum}(R_{A}^{-1}-I)}{8}}
$$
Here $R_A$ is both row and column wise indexing using $A$.

And $\text{sum}(R_A)$ is the sum of all elements.

Comment: It's Gaussian Copula evaluated at $\vec{0}$.